# Good variance test when the distributions have different shapes but I really want to test the variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, inference, f-test, levenes-test

Consider $X\sim N(1,1)$ and $Y\sim exp(1)$. The distributions are totally different, but they do have equal variance, so if I were to sample from these and test for unequal variance, I would not want to reject a null hypothesis of variance equality.

I am finding that the usual suspects for variance testing reject too often. In my Monte Carlo simulations, the F-test (`var.test` in R), Brown-Forsythe (`car::leveneTest(…, center="median")`), Levene (`car::leveneTest(…, center="mean")`), Ansari-Bradley (`ansari.test`), and permutation testing (my own custom function) all rejected considerably more often that my chosen $\alpha$. These tests are overpowered for this situation. I suspect (particularly for Ansari-Bradley) that this is due to the tests examining some kind of surrogate for variance (some kind of "scale" parameter) rather than variance itself, and they are finding that $X$ and $Y$ do differ on that surrogate.

What would be a test that has appropriate power for my $X$ and $Y?$

Comment: The choice of test ought to depend on the amount of data and on any additional assumptions you can make about the distributions.  Could you provide some specifics of your intended application?

Comment: For amount of data, I won’t be working with 3-4 observations. I would expect (usually) at least dozens of not hundreds of points. For intended application, I have bizarre empirical distributions that don’t seem to follow the named distributions. Mostly, I’m content to use something like Ansari-Bradley (a collaborator adores it), but I’d sure like to see something that really examines variance and not the “scale” that Ansari-Bradley examines, since that results in a false rejection of variance equality for $N(1,1)$ and $exp(1)$.

Comment: For comparing variances you typically need much more data than for comparing means.  In this light, even a few hundred values is not a large dataset.  The A-B test is a rank sum test, which means it may be appropriate for your broad nonparametric assumption: but it also implies it may lack power.  The power can be regained to the extent you can narrow your characterization of the distributions your are comparing. I don't follow your distinction between a scale parameter and variance, because the two are interchangeable in any scale family (which this is).

Comment: The normal $X$ and exponential $Y$ are in the same scale family?

Comment: Yes, because you have implicitly formulated this as a nonparametric problem.  If that's not what you mean--if instead you literally mean you *know* you have sampled from this Normal and this Exponential distribution--then there's nothing left to say.  In fact, you don't even need a sample to determine whether these distributions have equal variances!

Comment: How have I implicitly formulated this as a nonparametric problem? (I’m content to post that as a separate question, if the response warrants that.)

Comment: (1) You haven't formulated it as a parametric problem.  (2) You explicitly envision using non-parametric tests, including your own permutation test.  But you're being coy: if you have a parametric family of distributions in mind, then please disclose it!

Comment: I think what I want is something like the central limit theorem to kick in for a variance test like it does for t-testing means (which it most certainly does fit my normal/exponential example). // I just picked that normal/exponential example because the shapes are super different, even though the populations have equal mean and variance.

Comment: Right: I understood, and I think most readers will understand, that those two distributions are just an example.  But--especially in this nonparametric setting where you have made no assumptions to control the kurtosis of the distribution and you aren't dealing with really huge datasets--it would be foolhardy to rely on the CLT.  That's why I originally asked about dataset size.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the means of the two distributions are equal. So instead of using a variance test, you can test the hypothesis $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]$.

Comment: This is an interesting idea, but it turns out to give too many type I errors, even when I subtract each variable’s mean from itself to work with zero-mean empirical distributions.

Comment: The OP hasn't suggested they would assume the means are equal.  Regardless, how would you test equality of the expected squares?  Remember, one explicit assumption is that "the distributions are totally different," so unless there is a huge amount of data, applying a standard t-test would be questionable.

Comment: Wilcoxon's test is designed for this.

Comment: Could you please explain how Wilcoxon's test handles this? Just square the values and throw them in `wilcox.test` in R?

Comment: yes, pass in the two sets of (squared) values, with paired=False